# opencv.js Otsu threshold

Tags: javascript, opencv, computer-vision

I'm using opencv.js.

I'm trying to find the best way to implement a binary filter on images taken from a mobile phone, in order to clearly see text on the image.  Adaptive Thresholds have not been great - too much noise.  I'm trying to get an Otsu threshold to work and I'm failing.

From [tutorials in the other OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) it looks like you'd ideally do a Gaussian Blur, then do an Otsu threshold (passing 0 in as the threshold value).

> For threshold value, simply pass zero. Then the algorithm finds the optimal threshold value and returns you as the second output, retVal

When I use 0 as the threshold value I get an all white result.  If I pass in something reasonable (e.g. 128), I get a decent result, but some darker areas of the image are washed out.  How can I get this "Optimal Threshold" (pass zero) to work for opencv.js?

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
let ksize = new cv.Size(3, 3);

//Blur & conver to gray
cv.GaussianBlur(src, dst, ksize, 0);
cv.cvtColor(dst, dst, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, 0);


/* PROBLEM HERE: 
*    passing 0 returns all white, passing 128 is a reasonable result
*/
cv.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY&cv.THRESH_OTSU);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is this line

```
cv.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY&cv.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Since cv.THRESH_BINARY & cv.THRESH_OTSU = 0,

you actually doing this

```
cv.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, 0);   <===== 0 = cv.THRESH_BINARY
```

To append a flag to another flag should use "OR" operator.

So this line should change to

```
cv.threshold(dst, dst, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image has more content than just the text, a global thresholding method (such as Otsu) will fail.

Keep your adaptive threshold but add a small positive or negative constant to the threshold(s).

Comment: What do you mean by "it will fail"?  Do you mean it won't perform well?  The Otsu docs don't mention only having text.  The adaptive threshold needs a varying constant based on the picture taken, and it seems to add salt and pepper noise no matter what.  That's why I was hopeful when I saw the following in the Otsu docs: "For threshold value, simply pass zero. Then the algorithm finds the optimal threshold value and returns you as the second output, retVal.".  But either I'm using it wrong, or it doesn't work in OpenCV.js.

Comment: @BRass: it can compute an irrelevant threshold.

Answer (score 1):

There is no AUTOMATIC WAY to get "Optimal Threshold".

But you can try to use [Adaptive Threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#adaptivethreshold) and I think [CLAHE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) maybe helpful in thresholding issues.

Comment: Thanks.  I have used an Adaptive Threshold with the Gaussian method.  It does OK, but it ends up creating salt and pepper noise.  You noted there is no Automatic Way to get optimal threshold.  Any idea why the opencv docs state below for OTSU?  "For threshold value, simply pass zero. Then the algorithm finds the optimal threshold value and returns you as the second output, retVal."  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: @BRass OTSU method works for region of image. It can be found 'optimal' value but it can't be 'good' value for entire image human's seeing.